# How to create a very large 2 dimensional matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I need a two dimensional matrix with 50,000 rows and 50,000 columns, each element set to value 0, while being easy on the memory.

I tried this:

```
value = 5
a = [0] * value
b = [a] * value
b[2][3] = 5
print b
```

Which gives me

```
[[0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0]]
```

I know that list b is just a reference to list a 5 times. Is there any way to create this matrix so that modifying one element does not effect others?

Comment: You don't want to store a sparse matrix in a 2d array. Takes too much memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix

Comment: Can you install SciPy? `scipy.sparse` provides efficient implementations of all the standard sparse matrix formats, which are going to be much better than anything you write yourself.

Comment: @user2357112 I have SciPy installed. Can you tell me how to create a 5000X5000 matrix using scipy.sparse? will i be able to change values of matrix by indices?

Comment: @Karthik: `scipy.sparse.appropriate_type((5000, 5000))`. You can assign values to cells of the matrix, although you should be aware of what sparse matrix representations perform best for what operations. `coo_matrix` is good for incremental updates.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank a lot.

Comment: @user2357112 I will assign values to the some(~100000) particular cells by several(10~20) increment by '1's . However, after assigning, I need access to the saved values periodically. Which one do you suggest?

Comment: @Karthik: `dok_matrix` is good for initial construction and efficient single-element access. Depending on what you're doing with the matrix, you may want to convert to other formats for things like matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Karthik please consider accepting any answer if it solved your question. You can do that by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. It helps the community here in StackOverflow if someone in the future faces the same problem as you. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `numpy` there is a builtin method for this:

```
>>> np.zeros((10,10))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If not you can use list comprehensions, though it will be quite slow.

```
[[0 for r in range(10)] for c in range(10)]
```

Do note that there are much more efficient ways to store sparse matrices, such as using scipy.

Answer (score 1):

It is very inefficient for a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) but you may use:

```
>>> mat = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(3)]
>>> mat
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

(Consider using [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) instead)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
value = 5
b = [[0 for x in range(value)] for y in range(value)]
b[2][3] = 5
print( b)
```

Result:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```